# Adobe Dreamweaver Extensions

Tags: c++, dreamweaver, embedded-resource

Does anyone know if its possible to turn off dreamweavers "custom icons" that it shows in the file browser so you can see the standard system-cache ones instead?

Something I'm trying to do via an extension but I cant find where its coming from in the large pile of XML files that is dreamweaver.

As the guy below pointed out this isn't available in the API; does anyone know a way of disabling the icons elsewhere (i.e which of the hundreds of files the icons are stored in) so I can in theory patch the file... can see that upsetting adobe but who cares.

Literally Looking for an if so, how.

Ta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its actually impossible via the extension interface; but is possible by editing the Dreamweaver library files.

Rubbish solution though and would never make it through adobe-exchange

Answer (score 1):

The icons displayed within the Files panel aren't controlled via the Dreamweaver API, so so can't change the icons used from the extensibility layer. Files that Dreamweaver doesn't know how to handle such as .png appear to use system icons (for me on Windows that means the same icons that Windows Explorer uses), but it's not entirely consistent, for example, .swf files for me show up with the Flash stylized "f" icon rather than what my system shows which is the unknown icon.

Those document types that are associated with Dreamweaver, such as .htm and .xml will show up in the Files panel with a Dreamweaver specific icon. I suppose it is possible to remove those files type from Dreamweaver being able to recognize them, but then Dreamweaver wouldn't be able to open and display them properly. So that won't get you what you want.

Comment: Crap; I could grow to hate adobe... more